# Derivative and second derivative of scaled logistic

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am implementing some custom loss functions for an AI project and my calculus is very rusty...

I need the first and second derivative of variants of the scaled logistic/sigomoid function $S(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}$

According to [this link](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Logistic_function#) and others, the first derivative of $S(x)$ when $k=1$ is $S'(x) = S(x)(1-S(x))$, and the second derivative: $S''(x) = S(x) (1-S(X)) (1-2S(X))$, but how does changing $k$ affect this result?

Comment: You need to polish up the chain rule. Or use wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+1%2F(1-exp(-kx))

Comment: True re chain rule, and indeed rest of my calculus. The trouble with alpha is it doesn't give the cleaner results above. Obv the results are equivalent but as I'm implementing in a tight code loop something neat like g'(x) = g(x)(1-g(x)) has major benefits.

Comment: Use algebra to simplify the wolfram answer. Compute the exponential once and save it.

Comment: The wolfram alpha link has a typo. It should be a plus in the denominator: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+1%2F%281%2Bexp%28-kx%29%29

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this very late answer, but let's differentiate!

---

We use [the chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$$F'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x),$$
where $F'(x) = f(g(x))$ and $f'(x)$ is the first derivative of $f(x)$.

---

So let's start with the first derivative:

$$S(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}=(1+e^{-kx})^{-1}$$

Let's denote $f(x)=x^{-1}$ and $g(x)=1+e^{-kx}$

Let's calculate:

$$g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(1+e^{-kx})=\frac{d}{dx}1+\frac{d}{dx}e^{-kx}=0+h(x)=h'(x)$$

where $h(x)=e^{-kx}$.

Let's calculate:

$$h'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}e^{-kx}$$

Let's denote $i(x)=e^x$ and $j(x)=-kx$

Let's move on:

$$j'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(-kx)=-k\frac{d}{dx}x=-k$$

$$i'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

By the chain rule:

$$h'(x)=i'(j(x))j'(x)=-ke^{-kx}$$

Then,

$$g'(x)=h'(x)=-ke^{-kx}$$

$$f'(x)=-x^{-2}$$

By the chain rule,

$$S'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)=-(1+e^{-kx})^{-2}\cdot (-ke^{-kx})=\frac{ke^{-kx}}{(1+e^{-kx})^2}$$

---

Now the second derivative:
$$S''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}S'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{ke^{-kx}}{(1+e^{-kx})^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$$

With the quotient rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\frac{a'(x)b(x)-b'(x)a(x)}{b(x)^2}$$

$$a'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(ke^{-kx})=k\cdot h'(x)=-k^2e^{-kx}$$

$$b'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(1+e^{-kx})^2=\frac{d}{dx}c(d(x))$$

where $c(x)=x^2$ and $d(x)=1+e^{-kx}$

$$c'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$$

$$d'(x)=g'(x)=-ke^{-kx}$$

By the chain rule,

$$b'(x)=c'(d(x))d'(x)=2(1+e^{-kx})\cdot(-ke^{-kx})=-2ke^{-kx}(1+e^{-kx})$$

With the quotient rule,

$$S''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\frac{a'(x)b(x)-b'(x)a(x)}{b(x)^2}=\frac{-k^2e^{-kx}\cdot (1+e^{-kx})^2 - (1+e^{-kx})\cdot ke^{-kx}}{(-2ke^{-kx}(1+e^{-kx}))^2}=4e^{kx}+\frac{e^{kx}}{4k(1+e^{-kx})}=-\frac{k^2(e^{kx}-1)e^{kx}}{(e^{kx}+1)^3}$$

So this is all.

P.S. Maybe it is very long, but I have included every step. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Happy differentiating!

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarize in a succinct form.

For general $k$, $S'(x) = k S(x) (1-S(x))$, and $S''(x) = k^2 S(x) (1-S(x)) (1-2S(x))$.

For an even more general logistic function $S_C(x)=\frac{C}{1+e^{-kx}}$ with magnitude $C$, the derivatives are $S_C'(x) = (\frac{k}{C}) S_C(x) (C-S_C(x))$, and $S_C''(x) = (\frac{k}{C})^2 S_C(x) (C-S_C(x)) (C-2S_C(x))$.

Shifting of $x \to x - \mu$ does not affect these results.

Answer (score 0):

[this old question "re-surfaced" recently and seemed worth a look]

There are times when the first derivative of a function is straightforward enough to obtain, but the second derivative will take a lot of writing to develop by applying the Quotient Rule.  This situation can be a good place to use implicit differentiation.

You've already been shown in **User123**'s answer that the Chain Rule gives you $$ [ \ e^{u} \ ]' \ \ = \ \ e^{u} \ · \ u' \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ [ \ e^{-kx} \ ]' \ \ = \ \  e^{-kx} \ · \ [ \ -kx \ ]' \ \ = \ \ e^{-kx} \ · \ (-k) \ \ , $$
for which we will have a little use.

Since we have $ \ S(x) \ = \ \frac{1}{1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx}} \ \ , \ $ we can re-arrange this as $ \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})·S \ = \ 1 \ \ . \ $  Implicit differentiation (and use of the Product Rule) produces
$$ [ \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})·S \ ]' \ \ = \ \ [ \ 1 \ ]' \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})'·S \ + \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})·S' \ \ = \ \ 0  $$
$$ ( \ [ \ 1 \ ]'  +  [ \ -k·e^{ \ -kx} \ ] \ ) ·S \ + \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})·S' \ \ =  \ \  0 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ (1  +  e^{ \ -kx})·S' \ \ = \ \ -( \ 0  +  [ \ -k·e^{ \ -kx} \ ] \ ) ·S  \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1 \ ]} $$ $$  \Rightarrow \ \ S' \ \ = \ \ \frac{k·e^{ \ -kx}}{1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx}}  ·S \quad \mathbf{[ \ 2 \ ]}  $$

The first derivative can then be expressed in various ways.  Inserting $ \ S(x) \ $ into equation $ \ \mathbf{2} \ $ yields $ S'(x) \ \ = \ \ \large{ \frac{k·e^{ \ -kx}}{(1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx})^2}   } \ \     $ $ \mathbf{[ \ 3 \ ]} \ \ , \ $ which is the form provided by something like WolframAlpha.  Since
$$ 1 \ - \ S(x) \ \ = \ \ \frac{ ( \ 1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx} \ ) \ - \ 1}{1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ e^{ \ -kx} }{1 \ + \ e^{ \ -kx}} \ \ , \quad \mathbf{[ \ 4 \ ]}  $$

we can write equation $ \ \mathbf{2} \ $ as $ \ \boxed{ \ S'(x) \ = \ k·S(x)·[ \ 1 \ - \ S(x) \ ] \ } \ \ , \ $ which is the form in which you are interested. (Referring back to equation $ \ \mathbf{3} \ \ , \ $ we note that this can also be expressed as $ \ S'(x) \ \ = \ \    k·e^{ \ -kx}·[ \ S(x) \ ]^2 \ \ . \ ) \    $

Applying implicit differentiation to the result in the box once more produces:

$$ [ \ S' \ ]' \ \ = \ \    k·[ \ S·( \ 1 \ - \ S \ ) \ ]' $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ S'' \ \ = \ \    k·( \ S'·[ \ 1 \ - \ S \  ]  \ + \  S·[ \ 1 \ - \ S \  ]' \ ) \ \  = \ \     k·( \ S'·[ \ 1 \ - \ S \  ]  \ + \  S·[   -  S'   ] \ ) $$
$$ = \ \     k·S'·( \  1 \ - \ S \  - \  S \ ) \ \ = \ \ k·S'·( \  1 \ - \ 2·S  \ )  \quad \mathbf{[ \ 5 \ ]} $$

[inserting our result for $ \ S'(x) \  ] $

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \boxed{ \ S''(x) \ \ = \ \  k^2·S(x)· [ \ 1 \ - \ S(x)  \ ] · [ \ 1  \ - \ 2·S(x) \ ] \ } \ \ . $$

This approach will also make it easier to contemplate finding higher derivatives of $ \ S(x) \ \ , \ $ compared to   "digging out" these relations from repeated applications of the Quotient Rule.